# Access for SQS "DeleteMessageBatch"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-sqs

I'm trying to set up IAM so a service can access SQS queues from another. Unfortunately I'm having issues getting access to 'DeleteMessageBatch'

I took a look at what IAM gives and that doesn't seem to be an available permission:

[image: example]

I've given permission to DeleteMessage but I'm still blocked when invoking DeleteMessageBatch. Is there someway to add permission for this?

Comment: There is no DeleteMessageBatch API call.  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazonsqs.html Add in the language and the SDK version you're using.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add the permission `sqs:DeleteMessageBatch` to the policy. It used to be in the IAM docs but [has been removed](https://twitter.com/heyiamfloyd/status/1439061084237930496?s=20) in September '21.  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

There also used to be `sqs:ChangeMessageVisibilityBatch` and `sqs:SendMessageBatch`.